# Why is the download speed so slow while sharing a file over my home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, file-transfer, speed

I am trying to transfer a file having size of 700 MB from one of my PC at home to another PC which are both connected to the same Wi-Fi hotspot. It boasts of having a download speed upto 150 Mbps. But, when I try downloading a file over the home network, the speed is phenomenally less (only gives an average speed of 500 KBps). Also, I am copying the file from another computer to a removable microSD card (which have a write speed of atleast 10 MBps) connected to my PC via adapter.

I searched for this problem on the web and found this: [Why is the file copy speed over wifi so slow?](https://superuser.com/questions/197247/why-is-the-file-copy-speed-over-wireless-so-slow)

But the accepted answer isn't valid for my case since my speed is substantially less:

[image]

Technical specs of the dongle/hostpot:

[image]

Any suggestions to increase the download speed over the home network?

Comment: How can you transfer at 150Mbps if your SD card can only transfer at 10Mbps.. What speed do you get when you copy from SD card to the desktop of the local PC?

Comment: @CustomX The SD card has a minimum write speed of 10 MB(Big B) and read speed peaks up to 95MBPS. And I don't expect it to transfer at 150 Mbps, but 500KBPS is way below its normal speed. While copying from SD card to desktop, speed is around 26 MBPS, and copying from desktop to SD card also gives an average of 27 MBPS.

Comment: What other devices that operate in the 2.4GHz range are running at the same time as the transfer?

Comment: I have only this router at home and runs at 2.4 GHz.